# AppConfig не видит приложение

Tags: python, django

Python версии 3.9,
Django версии 3.2.5

На этапе запуска проекта происходит ошибка с приложением 'imagesApp' в settings.py (ошибка скорее всего именно там, т.к. при попытке убрать все упоминания моего приложения в urls.py не происходят никакие изменения). Ошибка следующего содержания:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/dmitriy/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-imageshare-9ikUb5f--py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dmitriy/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-imageshare-9ikUb5f--py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/dmitriy/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-imageshare-9ikUb5f--py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/dmitriy/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-imageshare-9ikUb5f--py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/dmitriy/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-imageshare-9ikUb5f--py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dmitriy/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-imageshare-9ikUb5f--py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/dmitriy/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-imageshare-9ikUb5f--py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/dmitriy/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-imageshare-9ikUb5f--py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 212, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imagesApp'
```

Cам settings.py:

```py
"""
Django settings for imageShare project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'imagesApp.apps.ImagesappConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'imageShare.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'imageShare.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'django_db',
        'USER': 'dimalunev',
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('PSQL_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'imageShare', 'static')
]


# Media files

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')


# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

INTERNAL_IPS = [
    '127.0.0.1',
]
```

Не думаю, что это связано с плохим неймингом (что django как-то не так обрабатывает модули приложений с подобными названиями), так как только что перед публикацией вопроса опробовал другие названия для модулей - всё также.

Comment: У вас, где приложение лежит?

Comment: Мне сейчас так стыдно стало за свою невнимательность, что и словами не описать. Ситуация такая: я создавал приложение из папки перед проектом командой ```python imageShare/manage.py startapp imagesApp``` и, понятное дело, приложение создалось не в корне, а там, где я вызвал эту команду. Сейчас перекинул папку в нужное место и всё заработало. 1 маленький наводящий вопрос, а решил мне весь вопрос. Извиняюсь за засорение сайта глупым вопросом на "не увидел/не заметил".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Ответ:

Приложение создалось не в корне django-проекта, а в папке до него (где виртуальное окружение, папка .git и т.д.). Перебросил модуль "imagesApp" повыше в корень django-проекта, всё заработало.

---

Поучительный вопрос. Будьте внимательны.